# means of vectors in dataframe by factor

Tags: r, vector, apply, mean, lapply

I am trying to create a new dataframe that is a condensed version of a series of vectors.

while my data is built something like

```
mat <- matrix(1:18, 6) 
g <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
df <- cbind(g, mat)
```

I would like to achieve

result_df like

```
a 1.5 7.5 13.5
b 3.5 9.5 15.5
c 5.5 11.5 17.5
```

I am running into trouble when I try the for loop, is there a way lapply() or apply() can do this natively? is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You may want to begin with a data frame instead of a matrix.

Comment: awesome. my data is in a dataframe, I will try this.. thank you @Zhenyuan Li

Comment: @ZiaRanks - Well your example isn't

Comment: yeah... had to be there... you could look at edits and see this but no worries. I think we got it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, that might be more flexible for future needs, is to use `dplyr`. This requires the data to be in a data.frame, but it sounds like that is what you have anyway.

```
df <- data.frame(g, mat)

df %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
```

It groups by the `g` column, then takes a mean of all of the remaining columns. It returns:

```
      g    X1    X2    X3
1     a   1.5   7.5  13.5
2     b   3.5   9.5  15.5
3     c   5.5  11.5  17.5
```

Which I believe is your desired outcome. If combined with `tidyr`, it may also make it easier to use/access those means by putting them in a long format

```
df %>%
  gather(Measurement, Value, -g) %>%
  group_by(g, Measurement) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Value))
```

returning:

```
      g Measurement  mean
1     a          X1   1.5
2     a          X2   7.5
3     a          X3  13.5
4     b          X1   3.5
5     b          X2   9.5
6     b          X3  15.5
7     c          X1   5.5
8     c          X2  11.5
9     c          X3  17.5
```

Comment: there are 2151 values so it gets really long but these are very good solutions. Thank you @MarkPeterson

Comment: In this case, "really long" may actually make things easier. With that many values, you likely aren't looking at it directly often anyway. Many plotting approaches, particularly `ggplot2`, work more easily with long data. Similarly, it can make it easier to grab similar measurement types, particularly if the names of the values are similar to each other.

Comment: That is what I keep reading. I am still learning the melt and cast stuff though...

Comment: I hear you @ZiaRanks It took me a while, but I came around to long data for a large range of things. It isn't always appropriate, but when it is: wow can it make a difference. If you are just exploring, I would recommend the [tidyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html). It is a bit different syntax to get used to then from `reshape2`, but it fits really nicely with a lot of the other `tidyverse` packages and has some advantages (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

I have two options, depending on whether you want to first do row operation first or column operation.

The column-first option will loop through all columns using `lapply`, then uses `tapply` to find mean by group for each column.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat, tapply, INDEX = g, mean))
```

The row-first option will split the data frame by rows into several groups, then uses `sapply` to find column mean for each sub data frame.

```
## implicit splitting
do.call(rbind, by(dat, g, sapply, mean))

## explicit splitting
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, g), sapply, mean))
```

---

If you have a matrix `mat` rather than a data frame, we can similarly do

```
apply(mat, 2L, tapply, INDEX = g, mean)
```

and

```
do.call(rbind, by(mat, g, colMeans))
```

---

**test data**

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = 1:6, V2 = 7:12, V3 = 13:18)

mat <- matrix(1:18, 6)

g <- gl(3, 2, labels = letters[1:3])
```

Comment: Great solution.. for my purposes the answer provided by @MarkPeterson is more relevant but they both work.